# CakePHP Email Transport Encoding

Tags: cakephp

I've created a custom transport for CakeEmail (to allow me to use Mandrill to send email). However, whenever I access the content of the message (which is cake email template driven), it doesn't encode the characters correctly (it changes 'é' to 'Ã©', etc). If I use CakeEmail and bypass the transport, it displays the characters correctly in the email. I've narrowed this down to $email->message('html') in the transport code. If I output $email->message('html'), the characters are already incorrect.

```
App::uses('AbstractTransport', 'Network/Email');
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

class MandrillTransport extends AbstractTransport {
    public function send(CakeEmail $email) {
        debug($email->message('html'));exit;
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably have an encoding mismatch somewhere, if for example your `App.encoding` doesn't match your `CakeEmail::$charset`, `CakeEmail` would try to convert the content from `App.encoding` to `CakeEmail::$charset`.

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../2.6.2/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L1338](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.2/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L1338)**

If for example the former were `iso-8859-1`, and the latter `utf-8`, just like the content, you would end up with the result you are showing here.

```
// outputs Ã© when displayed as utf-8/unicode
echo mb_convert_encoding('é', 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1');
```

You'll have to do some further debugging to trace down where exactly things are going wrong.